# JSON to HTML with breaklines, angular-translate

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using Angular-translate and I am trying to load a text from JSON with breakline, but the html is not recognizing.

**JSON:**

```
"ABOUT": {
    "headline":"Every day\n every moment",
    "span": "Be Like"
}
```

**ANGULARJS:**

```
.config(function($translateProvider) {

// Sanitize
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escaped');

// Load  JSON
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/app/languages/app-',
    suffix: '.json'
});
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

**HTML:**

```
        <h2> <span>{{ 'ABOUT.span' | translate }}</span>
        {{ 'ABOUT.headline' | translate }}
       ....
```

Is there some way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `white-space:pre;` in `css` so it would be like that in your html

`<h2 style="white-space:pre;"> <span>{{ 'ABOUT.span' | translate }}</span>{{ 'ABOUT.headline' | translate }} </h2>`

here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Bjs6LC9Z9Fy1v5ULqlVW?p=preview